# IE11 innerHTML strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, riot.js

I have very strange behaviour with element.innerHTML in IE11.

As you can see there: http://pe281.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html, some `riotjs` expressions are not evaluated.

[image]

I've tracked it down to 2 things:
- the euro sign above it. It's encoded as `&euro;`, but I have the same behaviour with `\u20AC` or `&#8364;`. It happens with all characters in the currency symbols range, and some other ranges. Removing or using a standard character does not cause the issue.
- The way `riotjs` creates a custom tag and template. Basically it does this:

```
var html = "{reward.amount.toLocaleString()}<span>&#8364;</span>{moment(expiracyDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}";
var e = document.createElement('div');
e.innerHTML = html;
```

In the resulting `e` node, `e.childNodes` returns the following array:

```
[0]: {reward.amount.toLocaleString()}
[1]: <span>€</span>
[2]: {
[3]: moment(expiracyDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}
```

Obviously nodes 2 and 3 should be only one. Have them split makes riot not recognizing an expression to evaluate, hence the issue.

But there's more: The problem is not consistent, and for instance cannot be reproduced on a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5wg3zxk5/4/, where the html string is correctly parsed.

So I guess my question is how can some specific characters change the way element.innerHTML parses its input? How can it be solved?

Comment: I'm not able to recreate this issue when I visit the page you've linked in your question and view it in IE11? Was this resolved?

Comment: Not resolved, but I used a (dirty) workaround: not having the euro sign in the HTML but as content of a css `:after` pseudo-element. The link is our staging env, and the fix has been deployed. Not resolved though.

Comment: Is there a way we can reproduce this error so we can figure out what's going on? Since you patched it, I'm unsure how to examine what's going on.

Comment: It's not office hours now in France, but I'll deploy a version with the issue to another env tomorrow and will update the link.

Comment: Awesome - I will stand by to take a look when it's ready.

Comment: What doctype are you using? HTML5, 4, XHTML?

Comment: @try-catch-finally: HTML5: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I checked the link now, some templates are not rendering even thought they don't include the euro sign, like: <span class="date">{moment(expiracyDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</span>

Comment: Could you reproduce the problem on the jsfiddle? It seems to be ok there (?)

Comment: Nope, cannot consistently reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

**`.childNodes` is a generated array (...well NodeList) that is filled with `ELEMENT_NODE` but may also be filled with: `ATTRIBUTE_NODE`, `TEXT_NODE`, `CDATA_SECTION_NODE`, `ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE`, `ENTITY_NODE`, `PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE`, `COMMENT_NODE`, `DOCUMENT_NODE`, `DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE`, `DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE`, `NOTATION_NODE`, ...**

You probably want **only nodes** from the type: **`ELEMENT_NODE`** *(div and such..)* and maybe also `TEXT_NODE`.

Use a simple loop to keep just those nodes with `.nodeType === Element.ELEMENT_NODE` (or just compare it to its enum which is `1`).

You can also just use the much more simpler alternative of `.children`.

Comment: That is fixing the symptoms, not any evidence of the root cause. Besides, `childNodes` is not used in the code, it's just to show the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<br>` with `<br />` (they are self-closing tags). IE is trying to close the tags for you. That's why you have doubled `br` tags

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `<br>`. See my edit with updated example without `br`, but still the issue.

Answer (score -2):

I think it should be something like this:

```
var html = {reward.amount.toLocaleString()}  + "&euro;<br>" +{moment(expiracyDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')} + " <br>";
var e = document.createElement('div');
e.innerHTML = html;
```

The stuff I removed from the quotes seem to be variables or other stuff, and not a string, so it should not be in quotes.

Comment: That stuff is part of a `riotjs` templating engine, so yes, it should be in quotes.